# Python list.remove(x) 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists shown below.  I'm trying to use the list.remove(x) function to remove the files that are in both list1 and list2, but one of my lists has file extensions while the other does not!  What should be my approach!?

```
List1 = ['myfile.v', 'myfile2.sv', 'myfile3.vhd', 'etcfile.v', 'randfile.sv']
List2 = ['myfile', 'myfile2', 'myfile3']

#This is in short what I would like to do, but the file extensions throw off
#the tool!
for x in List2:
   List1.remove(x)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really dangerous to loop over a list as you are removing items from it. You'll nearly always end up skipping over some elements.

```
>>> L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> for x in L:
...     print x
...     if x == 2:
...         L.remove(2)
... 
1
1
2
3
3
```

It's also inefficient, since each `.remove` is O(n) complexity

Better to create a new list and bind it back to `list1`

```
import os
list1 = ['myfile.v', 'myfile2.sv', 'myfile3.vhd', 'etcfile.v', 'randfile.sv']
list2 = ['myfile', 'myfile2', 'myfile3']
set2 = set(list2)  # Use a set for O(1) lookups
list1 = [x for x in list1 if os.path.splitext(x)[0] not in set2]
```

or for an "inplace" version

```
list1[:] = [x for x in list1 if os.path.splitext(x)[0] not in set2]
```

for a truly inplace version as discussed in the comments - doesn't use extra O(n) memory. And runs in O(n) time

```
>>> list1 = ['myfile.v', 'myfile2.sv', 'myfile3.vhd', 'etcfile.v', 'randfile.sv']
>>> p = 0
>>> for x in list1:
...     if os.path.splitext(x)[0] not in set2:
...         list1[p] = x
...         p += 1
... 
>>> del(list1[p:])
>>> list1
['etcfile.v', 'randfile.sv']
```

Comment: The latter isn't really "in-place"—it still builds a copy, and then mutates the original list to match the copy. There is probably no good reason to actually want an in-place mutation here—but if you do want that, you have to actually use `remove`/`del`/`pop`/etc. (It's a great answer in every other way, especially the explanation for why the OP should just create a new list.)

Comment: @abarnert, it's "in-place" in so far as there may be other references to list1 that you are expecting to see the deletions

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by "builds a copy, and then mutates the original list to match the copy." Mutating the original list to match the copy is why other references will see the deletions. But it's still not an in-place algorithm it's a copying algorithm.

Comment: @abarnert, I think the only reason to use a fully in-place version is when you can't afford the extra RAM. In this case the list is so large that the O(n**2) behaviour from using `.remove` etc is significant. It's possible to do this in O(n) by making sure not to use `.remove`, `del`, `.pop` and instead keep an extra running pointer followed by a single truncate at the end.

Comment: @abarnert, I added this in-place version to my answer

Comment: I agree that he almost certainly doesn't want to do it in-place, for exactly the reasons you're explaining. And I probably would have just said that and left it there instead of showing how to do it if you really want to… since I can't +1 the answer again for the extra effort above and beyond, I'll +1 the comment. :)

Comment: @gnibbler `set(list2)` in the last sample will have O(n) memory, right? That too for each iteration?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I've used `n` for the length of list1, lets use `m` for the length of list2. you could leave that out I guess, but then you get O(1) memory at the expense of the O(m) lookups.

Comment: @gnibbler Sorry. I didnt understand that. Could you please elaborate

Comment: @thefourtheye, you can use `not in list2` in place of `not in set2`, but the lookups on a list need to scan the whole list. And I should have used my `set2` I defined at the top instead of creating it over and over. Let me just fix that

Comment: @gnibbler Exactly. This is what I wanted to see :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of it, if you want to use the `list.remove(element)`, as it is very easy to read for others, you can try the following. If you have a function f that returns true if the value is correct/passes certain tests as required,

Since this will NOT work:

```
def rem_vals(L):
    for x in L:
        if not f(x):
             L.remove(x)
```

for more than one value to be removed in the list L, we can use recursion as follows:

```
def rem_vals_rec(L):
    for x in L:
        if not f(x):
            L.remove(x)
            rem_vals_rec(L)
```

Not the fastest, but the easiest to read.